# Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type IBackupTableStorageService, key "" StructureMap library

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap, common-service-locator

I am facing issue of mapping. My solution is as below.

I have two projects

```
1. Azure Function (v1) project with Framework:  .Net Framework 4.7.2
2. Class Library               with Framework:  .Net Framework 4.7.2
```

In 1st project i have an azure function which is triggering using Queue and call my function BeginBackup(CancellationToken token, DateTime.Now()) which exist in my concreate class.

I am calling my function as below from my Azure function.

```
DependencyContext.Instance.Locator.GetInstance<IBackupTableStorageService>().BeginBackup(cancellationToken, SystemTime.UtcNow());
```

My DependencyContext.cs class is below.

```
using ClassLibrary1.BackupTableStorage;
using CommonServiceLocator;
using StructureMap;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AzureFunctionsProject.Functions
{
   public interface IDependencyContext
   {
        IServiceLocator Locator { get; }
   }

   public class DependencyContext : IDependencyContext
   {
       private static volatile IDependencyContext _instance;
       private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();

       public static IDependencyContext Instance
       {
           get
           {
               if (_instance == null)
               {
                   lock (SyncRoot)
                   {
                       if (_instance == null)
                       {
                           _instance = new DependencyContext();
                       }
                   }
               }

               return _instance;
            }
           set => _instance = value;
       }

       public IServiceLocator Locator { get; private set; }

       public DependencyContext()
       {
           Build();
       }

       private void Build()
       {
           var registry = new Registry();//Registry is the class belongs to StructureMap.
           var container = new Container();

           var serviceLocatorProvider = new StructureMapServiceLocator(container);
           ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocatorProvider);
           Locator = serviceLocatorProvider;

           // register the container itself
           registry.For<IServiceLocator>().Use(ServiceLocator.Current);

           // Apply the registry to the container
           container.Configure(x =>
           {
               x.AddRegistry<Domain.Registry>();
               x.AddRegistry(registry);
           });
       }
   }

   public class StructureMapServiceLocator : ServiceLocatorImplBase
   {
       private IContainer Container { get; set; }

       public StructureMapServiceLocator(IContainer container)
       {
           Container = container;
       }

       protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
           {
               return Container.GetInstance(serviceType);
           }

           return Container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
       }

       protected override IEnumerable<object> DoGetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
       {
           foreach (object obj in Container.GetAllInstances(serviceType))
           {
               yield return obj;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I have another Registery class which i have created which have mapping of my interface with my concrete class.

Registery.cs file is below.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.Domain
{
    public class Registry: StructureMap.Registry
    {
        public Registry()
        {

            // The Localization Service needs to be passed a function to record exceptions
            For<ILocalizationService>().Use<LocalizationService>()
            .Ctor<LocalizationService.LogException>().Is(context => CreateExceptionLogger(context));

            For<ICloudStorageWrapper>().Use<CloudStorageWrapper>();
            For<IBackupTableStorageService>().Use<BackupTableStorageService>();
        }

        private LocalizationService.LogException CreateExceptionLogger(IContext context)
        {
            return (ex, c, m) =>
            {
                var logger = context.GetInstance<ILogicalOperationsLogger>();
            logger.ErrorException(m, ex);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Like wise i have my Interface and respected to concreate class which has the definition of my method **BeginBackup(CancellationToken token, DateTime.Now());**

**I am getting exception in DoGetInstance method in DependencyContext.cs class.**

I am new in IoC and dependency injection, please let me know what i am doing wrong, if anything required to make question more clear please let me know.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: You can debug structuremap by calling container.WhatDoIHave() or container.WhatDidIScan(). http://structuremap.github.io/diagnostics/whatdoihave/

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the registration for `IServiceLocator` into the configure action. You can also remove the Registry-object you created:

```
   private void Build()
   {
       var container = new Container();

       var serviceLocatorProvider = new StructureMapServiceLocator(container);
       ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocatorProvider);
       Locator = serviceLocatorProvider;

       // Apply the registry to the container
       container.Configure(x =>
       {
           // register the container itself
           x.For<IServiceLocator>().Use(serviceLocatorProvider);
           x.AddRegistry<Domain.Registry>();
       });
   }
```

Comment: This solution is not working, actually I would like to say that problem is not in your solution. Problem is where class has parameterized constructor, and strange thing is 
 if parameter is .net type than it will work but if parameter is customize like ILogic, IWrapper etc. than it failes and give exception "Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type IExperimental, key \"\""